# How to deal with duplicate answers

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

A lot of times I'll be looking at a question and there will be one or two **really great answers**. *Upvote!*

Give it 2-3 minutes and the **same exact** answers will show up again from different users, typically with low reputation. How does Stack Overflow suggest going about dealing with such answers?

- Should I downvote them because they don't add anything new?
- Should we give them the benefit of the doubt that they did not see that the answer they are posting is already provided?

Comment: Sometimes I take a while to answer a question, and by the time I post it, there's already another answer.  If I think they're largely duplicates or if I think the other answer is better, I'll suggest the missing bits to the other answer-er and if they're incorporated, I'll delete my answer.  I'm just not that into building rep and would prefer a single solid and comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Edward I agree with you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If one answer is better than the other in any way, I'll upvote that one.

If both answers came in at about the same time (say, within 1 or 2 minutes of each other), and they both appear to be answering in good faith, I'll upvote both.

If the second answer clearly took a long time to come in, I'll sometimes leave a comment to the effect of "You're a bit late, aren't you?"

Comment: So you're saying that we should use discretion based on timing?

Comment: Well, if it took the second person 10 minutes to post essentially the same information as the first (especially if the answer is short), I don't think that deserves an upvote.

Comment: But does it deserve a downvote?

Comment: I downvote answers that are not useful, just like the tooltip on the downvote arrow says.

Comment: Okay. Good to know. Thanks for the info! It was something I always wondered.

Comment: And if someone posts a duplicate answer to an old question, I won't hesitate to dump it in a chatroom to get it nuked. The biggest offender is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator which attracts tons and tons of new users posting the same answer over and over again.

Comment: Then you'll be flagged as a rude uncaring mod for saying _You're a bit late, aren't you?_ !

Comment: @Mysticial: ACK.  Filed under "Weird things programmers find morbidly fascinating."

Comment: @bluefeet I feel there's a really good pregnancy joke in there somewhere.