# Are duplicate answers acceptable?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers, fastest-gun

I happened to notice [How to shorten switch case block converting a number to a month name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828098/how-would-you-shorten-this-switch-case-statement). Two [of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29828181/3148067) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29828248/3148067) answers are almost exactly the same (except whitespace) and both are nearly identical to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29828190/3148067). Two [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29830464/3148067) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29828180/3148067) propose slightly different techniques.

Is this something that is encouraged? If I think of a solution which turns out to be the same as existing answers, should I post it?

From [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252795/3148067) it seems that such duplicates are rarely deleted and seldom downvoted, but should they be posted in the first place?

Comment: It is not encouraged.  When you ask for a volunteer to delete his post, everybody says "the other guy".  The question is very trite, nobody worries about this.

Comment: See below for illustration of this principle. Duplicates saying the same thing aren't ideal, but they're pretty harmless. Plagiarism is a no-no. Fastest gun does apply here - for an easy question, lots of people will start typing an answer, and may well hit post before checking to see if anyone else has in the meantime.

Comment: I wonder about that nobody was able to find a duplicate for the question. I can't imagine this wouldn't be a dupe under the PHP tag and JS is similar popular, so ... .

Comment: what is the actual downside? If a few people respond with same thing it's clear to OP that there is consensus anyway. Have seen the consensus duplicates all be wrong though due to common misinterpretation of a question

Comment: related: [Vote to delete answers as duplicates of earlier answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243243/165773). For _extremely_ popular questions, there is even [authoritative guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773) for moderators to delete "*provably* duplicate" answers (your example unfortunately doesn't seem to qualify as such, with only ~6K views)

Answer (score 58):

That is an easy and clear question, with a simple and straightforward answer,

Thus there's no wonder it attracted lots of fast, correct and nearly identical answers. If you take a look, those three answers were posted within a span of less than 4 minutes, the first one less than four minutes after the queston.

The answerers most likely didn't see each others answers until after they posted.
Naturally, you should take into account whether your answer adds anything over pre-existing ones.

As an aside, looks like the same happened here!

Answer (score 31):

Personally, I refrain from posting duplicate answers.  I prefer *upvoting* instead.

Keep in mind that the *entire post* is the answer, so even if the code is (practically) identical the answers can still be distinct (in explanation, for example).  In these cases, like in the discussion you link, I vote based on the usefulness of the post.  This means upvoting for good explanation, or downvoting for poor explanation.

For your specific post, the timestamps of the two posts are within 10 seconds of each other (`15:37:51Z` and `15:37:59Z`) so the isn't any reason to suspect any foul play.

For cases where one answer is *significantly* older, truly duplicate answers are *not useful* (because they don't add anything new and only clutter up the page) and do deserve downvotes.

Comment: I posted a feature suggestion aimed to reduce the number of duplicate answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270027/encourage-deleting-ones-own-answer-in-favor-of-another-one-in-order-to-reduce-t

Comment: I think it is better  to post explanation as comments to existing answer, or the answer can be also edited.

Answer (score 18):

There's a few cases to consider before making an overall assessment.

1. The question is very easy, and a lot of people arrive at the same (or similar) solutions within minutes of it being posted.
2. The question is old and has one or two answers already, some of which may be already upvoted incredibly

With the first case, as we've previously established, a lot of people arrive at a solution and post it, and a lot of others that see them decide to upvote it emphatically.  This **isn't a problem**, although one hopes that, later on, an answer decides to break from the pack to add more useful information.

A personal strategy of mine has been to contribute to those sorts of questions in a way that increases the overall knowledge.  The answers I give may have similar code, but the explanation and the rationale behind the answer are at least explained if not different to the previous answers. This, I feel, is an appropriate action to take; if you *can* add more information to a question, you *should*.

The second case is more serious: someone's taken a previously existing answer and copied it.  Plagiarism aside, **no new information has been contributed** to an existing question, and is effectively taking up everyone's time and energy.  Answers like this **are a problem** and should be dealt with.

I wouldn't downvote a quick-draw simple question with lots of similar answers unless I could reason that the answer itself was wrong.  You're welcome to vote however you like in the end, but I would encourage you not to *over*react to these occurrences.

Comment: That hits it for me. If they are all around the same time, keep them, no harm done (one will get the first upvote and the top position, often). If it's a copy of a much older answer with no new information, I'd downvote it and possibly post a comment explaining that.

Comment: _"should be dealt with"_ -- just to be clear: in this scenario, where a duplicate answer is posted well after a previous answer, by "dealt with" you mean simply to downvote? Or is there some other action one should take (e.g. flag the post)? I'm assuming the former...that seems consistent with guidance in related discussions and the rest of your answer. But I want to make sure I (and anyone else reading) understands precisely what you mean.

Comment: Flags are to deal with scenarios where they're not an answer. Downvotes are for scenarios where they're poor quality answers. Downvoting would apply here.

Comment: @Sobrique, I posted a feature suggestion aimed to reduce the number of duplicate answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270027/encourage-deleting-ones-own-answer-in-favor-of-another-one-in-order-to-reduce-t

Answer (score 11):

> If I think of a solution which turns out to be the same as existing answers, should I post it?

- If you just post the exact same thing: **no!** There's no point.
- If you can provide extra details or a better way to do the same thing: **maybe!** Consider posting a comment instead if there's not a significant improvement.

In this case, it looks like the answers were posted at about the same time, which is also fine.

Answer (score 3):

Like most people, I’ve seen this sort of thing happen now and then (most recently today, hence finding my way here). I have found several discussions on this subject and I have to disagree with the general consensus (while some of the other threads are older than this one, I am posting a response here because it is both most active, and most descriptive of the issue).

Honestly, I really don’t see what reason there is to keep effectively identical answers. Whenever someone comes across a question that has them (as I [did today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233407/get-random-item-from-array)), the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4233407/timeline) of the question should be checked to determine which one was posted first and the others should be flagged for culling. I know this is not a popular idea since it means some people will lost a few points, but that’s how the site works: first answer gets the marks.

I felt it necessary to post this opinion because most people who responded to the questions about this subject seem to be wearing blinders and have echoed [@charlietfl’s sentiment of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291276/are-duplicate-answers-acceptable#comment182680_291276) *what is the actual downside?*

The answer is *plenty*. Aside from database bloat, page-load overhead, memory-overhead, processing overhead, and page clutter, the downside is that users will now need to look at each answer and manually, visually compare them to see how identical they each are and then to analyze any differences to figure out what effect they have (possibly implementing/compiling/running each one). That is an unnecessary and time-consuming burden that reduces the value of the question and its answers. Clearing out all of the effectively identical duplicates leaves only answers that provide some actual variation that is worthwhile.

Comment: You know we only ever soft-delete, right? So database-load won't change at all. Still, that was the weakest point, nearly felt like nit-picking...

Comment: I posted a feature suggestion aimed to reduce the number of duplicate answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270027/encourage-deleting-ones-own-answer-in-favor-of-another-one-in-order-to-reduce-t