# Edit vs New Answer

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-answers

I found a question which already has an answer, and my answer would be very similar.

In this case, what I should do:

- Edit the current posted answer, this way it would make his answer more complete and keep the page more 'clear'. But in this case, I would help another person to win reputation.
- Create a new answer that will be similar to the other, but a little more complete and earn my reputation.

What you guys think its the best approach?

Answer (score 13):

You should not be adding new content to someone else's answer.  If there is a small bit if information that you would like to add, you could post a comment to encourage the author to add it to their answer.  If it's something more substantial, you can post your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your answer is [*practically identical*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291276/are-duplicate-answers-acceptable), I suggest upvoting the other answer instead of posting.  Otherwise it depends on what you mean by "a little more complete".

If an explanation is different, I'd use a new answer.  It's wrong to put words into another user's post, and most explanations are too important and long for comments.  Besides, you could easily be misrepresenting the other user's intentions.

I'd use edits and comments for small clarifications, formatting, or other minor typos.

Regardless of the action you take, feel free to vote for the other answer based on it's helpfulness.  Since it is similar to your answer, chances are good you would have found it helpful.  But you can downvote it if you feel it is not helpful (for example, if it has the same code but a very confusing or even wrong explanation).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this scenario handled many times by an additional answer that clearly refers to a previous answer, then expands on it *in a substantial way*. No need to copy the part that would be the same, instead focus on enhancing the learning experience for the OP. For example, I've [used it myself here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17561753/1677912).

Questions can have multiple answers - but that doesn't mean it has to be a game of winners and losers.