# Should possible duplicate answers be flagged for special moderator attention?

Tags: support, flags

I was reviewing *First Posts* yesterday and came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30465838/3773066) that I believe doesn't add anything new that the well-established [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7609388/3773066) doesn't already cover.

In the past I've wanted to flag such answers as duplicates, but in the review flags there was no option for duplicates.  Due to this I always flagged for moderator attention with a link to the existing original answer.  These flags have always been rejected or time-decayed, despite that the "duplicate" answers are sometimes removed or closed.

In this case, I simply commented.  But what is the proper course of action?

- Comment?
- Vote down?
- Flag for moderator attention?
- Flag as *Not an answer*? (Possibly should have been a comment.)
- Something else?

Comment: Duplicate is NOT for answers... it`s for questions

Comment: Somewhat related: [Are duplicate answers (on the same question) acceptable?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291276/are-duplicate-answers-acceptable)

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes, thanks for noting that.  I've seen that post once and I totally agree that easy answers often get duplicated within minutes of each other.  In this case there was a large time discrepancy and I believe unwarranted.

Comment: Generally speaking - if you keep flagging the same type of post for the same reason and it keeps being rejected, you probably shouldn't be flagging that way.

Comment: @sphanley Precisely why I didn't flag this time and asked this question.  After two declines I decided not to go for strike three.  Side note: thanks for the edit. :)

Comment: @OhBeWise two tries is a very reasonable number to ask after. The way it was worded, wasn't sure if you'd tried a larger number of times!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two real situations here:

1. A user is plagiarizing content from another answer in his own answer.
2. A user is providing an answer to a question that is their own original content, but that has very similar information to other answers, and that you feel is not adding any additional value.

If you suspect the first case, flag for a mod.  You could comment if you want, depending on the situation, if you think you can resolve it (generally by having the user remove or properly cite the plagiarized content).

For the second case, if you feel that the post isn't useful and that it's not adding value beyond the answers already available, then you should be downvoting.  that is the appropriate tool to indicate that an answer isn't useful.  If you also want to comment to explain to the author why you feel the answer isn't useful, you're welcome to do so.  You should not be flagging such an answer.

Comment: Useful when commenting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing