# When your Answer is too similar for comfort to another that popped up while you wrote it

Tags: discussion, answers

Recently, it happened more then once to me that I was typing an answer, and while I was typing it had to go do something first, so I did that thing first and then returned to typing my answer. However, on submitting it I noticed to my shock that another, functionally identical (or very similar) answer from another user had popped up meanwhile. An example of this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216042/scanf-skipping-lines-in-visual-studio-2015/33216224#33216224)

In these cases, should I simply move on, mark my answer retroactively as community wiki, or delete it?

Comment: Either post it as a separate answer (no need for community wiki IMO) or just don't post it at all if you feel the other answer is adequate.

Comment: Is there a means by which I can see if another answer is written before submitting mine other then opening the question again in a new tab?

Comment: Not as far as I am aware and I'm not sure why it matters. You answered the question **independently** so you're entitled to any votes &/or rep that you might receive.

Comment: For any outsiders it could look like copying though

Comment: No, it really doesn't. It looks like you both came up with the same answer a few seconds or minutes apart. This happens all the time.

Comment: @Magisch You should get a "# new answer" notification below the question if any answers come in while you're typing. You can click on that and it will asynchronously load the answers and you can review them before you post yours. If they are too similar for comfort discard your answer, otherwise post it.

Comment: Related: [Are duplicate answers acceptable?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291276/4320665).  I personally would leave the answer if the explanations are different.  Otherwise, I like deleting the answer and upvoting the other one.  But that's just me.

Comment: Alternatively, since the question title is always a link to the question itself, you could re-open the question in a new tab to check for new content. The thing Dave Zych pointed out should work but this is a way to double check.