# What is the most appropriate way to behave when more users concurrently propose the same solution to a question?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

**Original post**

I am relatively new to SO and although I understand the basic rules of the site there is a more ethical mater that I don't know how to handle.

Another user and I provided our own answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083545/how-to-catch-a-filenotfoundexception-exception) question practically at the same time and with basically the same solution. Of course, in the event that our solution is correct, only one of us will get the accepted answer and relative reputation.

I later on edited my answer with snippets and a source link, but only for the benefit of the users seeking a solution, to provide an answer as *complete* as I can.

My fear is that this behavior might seem deliberately aggressive to the other answerer, just so that I can get reputation by trying to outclass his/her solution.

How should I behave in a situation like this? Is there a rule I should follow? Or am I thinking too much? I love our community and for this reason I want do to things right and avoid to be a jerk.

---

**Wrapping things up**

I'm writing this edit/summary to say that by accepting one answer I don't discard the other ones. I believe that more or less all your contributions, both answers and comments, where very insightful.

I see there is a general consensus among the participants in this post, which is that the main priority is to provide *good* answers to *good* questions, thus improving the quality of the site. Motives and methodology for doing so are irrelevant.

Providing an answer that partially overlaps with an existing one is ok as long as it presents a different point of view for the OP. Otherwise edits and comments to the original answer are the way to go for a healthy contribution.

Finally, one should deal with low quality questions and duplicates by flagging them appropriately and not answer them just for the sake of personal reputation.

Comment: Because, many features linked with reputation. Users are so eager to get it & ethics doesn't matter to them. A better explanation of this → [4 cramps of users on stack overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/5832518)

Comment: @Raju I understand that and I agree with you but I doesn't answer my question. Of course I want my share of compensation if I provide useful help but I'm not greedy. In the case I presented we wrote the same answer simultaniously so there were no greedy intentions from the both of us, it just so happen that way. Is there something I should do to not seem impolite or unethical?

Comment: Improving your answer is not aggressive.

Comment: Its *your* work, and therefore a reflection of *your* abilities. If you can improve it then you should for your own sake. The community will decide which answer they like (rightly or wrongly). The time to worry about someones feelings is when you are actually talking *to* them. Tone matters then, just as it does in the real world.

Comment: You could improve the other person's (identical) answer instead!

Comment: Very often, the appropriate thing to do is to close as duplicate.  If it's a simple question which a horde of fastest guns in the West are scrambling to answer before anybody else, it has probably been beaten to death many times before.

Comment: Might be quite related to old [Fastest Gun](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533/173052) - [Slowest Cheater](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19535/173052) problem. The thing is many people do strange tricks for reputation. But the main aim should be offering a good solution that could also help others with the same problem.

Comment: Relevant [Are duplicate answers acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291276/are-duplicate-answers-acceptable)

Comment: Hey man, sometimes the man with 0 upvotes gives the only working solution and claims the bounty. Sometimes it's even the man with -2. It's up to the asker to decide who helped him most and be fair, or just be a leecher and get help.

tl;dr - there's a reason the "unsung hero" achievment is kinda scarce.

Comment: @Shark, no doubt you mean "woman or man" by "man", except in the first instance of the word.

Comment: *My fear is that this behavior might seem deliberately aggressive to the other answerer, just so that I can get reputation by trying to outclass his/her solution.* - why is this a fear or concern, this is actually what **you are supposed to do**, as this helps the internet in general more than it does you.

Comment: @Mars actually, no. I'm pretty positive that the OP (Matei Radu) is a guy. Ergo, *man* it is. Edit: oh, but yeah, down below it's just a sexless noun, 'a person' if you like.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to add to what was already said, the fact that you are considering how it might be perceived is a good indication you are using a balanced approach, IMHO.

There are no hard and fast rules, AFAIK. Everyone approaches it differently. When that has happened to me, the questions I try and ask myself are:

1. Do I have something *significant* to contribute over the existing responses?

If the answer is "no", then an extra response saying the same thing is just noise IMO. So I usually delete my answer.

2. Is my extra information minor enough to be communicated through a "Comment" or "Edit" of an existing answer?

If I only have a *minor* changes, I often delete my answer and leave a comment instead. For small, but important changes (that do not conflict with the author's intent), I will edit the existing answer instead. If it is borderline, I leave a courtesy comment to the affect of *"BTW, I made change X in order to improve Y. If you do not like it, feel free to roll it back"*.

**If none of the above applies, I will not only leave my answer, but typically expand it, to provide as thorough an explanation as possible. Regardless of whether some of it overlaps with existing answers.**

Sure, courtesy is important. However, it is not about trying to be a nice guy versus a competitive jerk. The ultimate goal is to make the site a great resource of information for both ourselves and other developers. So if you can do that, within the site guidelines, by all means - please do.

Comment: Sometimes I start to leave a comment or make an edit, but realize that I should just post my own answer instead, because I want to explain the same general solution in a different way.  Or to point out some subtleties or potential issues that an existing answer doesn't address.

Comment: *explain ... in a different way* ... which is not duplication IMO.  We all absorb information differently. Presenting information from a different angle - may resonate more with some folks, so the additional perspective does add value to the thread.  However, other times a question has a very specific/narrow answer. On those threads, you frequently see multiple answers saying exactly the same thing (almost verbatim).  Not because of cheating, but simply because there aren't that many different ways to explain it. So the extra answers are more of a distraction/noise than anything else IMO.

Comment: One border case that might result in disaster is if two guys are posting the same solution at the same time and then seeing someone else posted already a full solution, both delete their solution.

Comment: Agreed, anything is possible. Though personally, I have seen more of the opposite. At least thus far :) Fortunately, "deleted" answers are not truly gone. They are still visible to 10K+ users. So someone could always vote to "undelete" one of them if needed.

Answer (score 56):

If you can improve the quality of the site by editing your answer to be more useful, do it. Just do it! No one really cares what are your motivations. No matter if you do it because you want to help the community, or because you are [greedy for some imaginary internet points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19522/310998), we will be grateful for any action that makes the site better.

Of course I'm not saying that caring only about reputation is good—if you for example answer bad questions that should be closed only to gain reputation, or if you're spamming the OP to accept your answer, that's not OK.

Comment: "greedy for some imaginary internet points" :D

Comment: They're not imaginary.  They're **not** they're **not** they're **not** [stamps foot]

Comment: Part of the point of rep is that the gamification encourages us to put more effort into making our answers good.  If the chance at gaining rep makes you put more effort into making your answer better, that's exactly what the system was designed to encourage.  It's also possible for two answers explaining the same idea / solution to both be useful, rather than one making the other redundant.  If they explain things from different angles, or focus on different aspects, they can both tell readers something useful.

Comment: "greedy for some imaginary internet points" - [there is an official term](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19522#19522).

Comment: Imaginary? No! I can **see** that little green square in my top bar that says +30. It wasn't there when I went to bed last night, and now I feel all warm and fuzzy.

Comment: Imaginary? Quite real I'd say, although made up by digital information instead of physical.

Comment: I agree, the green box that surprises me with different amounts does make me feel warm and fuzzy :D

Comment: They're like the points from Who's Line Is It Anyway - https://www.reddit.com/r/whoselineisitanyway/comments/x3oqn/the_points_that_dont_matter_for_each_cast_member/

Comment: Having just reached 200k, I can assure you that the <strike>struggle is</strike> points are real!

Comment: Sublimation is a good thing : "In psychology, sublimation is a mature type of defense mechanism where socially unacceptable impulses or idealizations are unconsciously transformed into socially acceptable actions or behavior, possibly resulting in a long-term conversion of the initial impulse." ie, even if you just do it because you want the points, it's still producing some good for society. ☺♥

Answer (score 17):

> My fear is that this behavior might seem deliberately aggressive to the other answerer, just so that I can get reputation by trying to outclass his/her solution.

Well if you in the event someone else posted literally the same answer you then take the time to even adapt because of that, I don't think it's aggressive, it's just responsive.

The other person perhaps might think it's aggressive (maybe if you refer to the other answer as a quick shot, lazy/crazy or other scurrilous language), but then you would have needed to ask that person in the first place (and perhaps watch your tone). But I don't want to say you did anything of that, more likely the opposite is the case as you ask on meta first.

- Edit your question as long as you think it needs editing.
- Competition is good for business.
- Stackoverflow is a browser game, don't take it too seriously.

Comment: *Stackoverflow is a browser game*, this is only true for april fools day? :D

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt no it's true 24/7. It's just well disguised.

Answer (score 4):

What is best on the internet?

To crush your enemies, to see their posts points be driven below yours, and to hear the lamentations of their compilers.

SO is both a game and a community.  The game is played to generate clear, concise and useful answers to programmers problems.  Part of the game is writing an answer, then making it *better*.

As a reward, you get imaginary internet points.  If you collect enough of that, you get an imaginary unicorn<sup>1</sup>.

So long as you play the game *and* generate quality content, nobody cares *why*.  If you outclass someone else's answer "aggressively" by adding details, sample code, images to help you -- **all the better**.  If you "cheat" by copying their content without acknowledgement, that isn't allowed, but the rules of the game are mostly aligned with the behavior that benefits not the other answerers, but the people reading the question later after having searched for a similar problem and found your Q&A.

Now, there are things that are meh, and things that are not ok.  Meh things include answering bad questions (which, honestly, the site can take or leave).  Bad things include harrassing posters to accept your answers or other answers to delete their content, or editing stuff to break the entire point of the website by making questions/answers *worse*.

But so long as you are providing better answers, feel free to aggressively edit and improve your answers all you want.

---

<sup>1</sup> No actual unicorn provided.

Comment: *No actual unicorn provided.*  Well thanks for crushing all my hopes and dreams.