# How should you treat an answer on question that is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

If a question is similar to any other post, we mark it as duplicate and close it.

I have refered [Answering a question, then closing it as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286072/answering-a-question-then-closing-it-as-duplicate), and even I agree that we should not answer a duplicate. But if someone chooses to answer, how should we handle this:

- Should we comment and request user to delete answer?
- Should we downvote and inform user that we should not answer duplicates?

Problem is, answer can be legit and downvoting can mislead others. So what is the right action.

**Note:** This is my first meta post. So if question is unclear or any information is missing, please let me know.

Comment: Quick, let me downvote some of the answers to this duplicate question.

Answer (score 4):

No and no. It is great that somebody has found a duplicate to close the question. But the user who posted that answer either wasn't aware that there was a duplicate to be found, or couldn't find it, and so instead chose to post a useful answer. There's absolutely no point in punishing that user for failing to find a useful duplicate, or to imply that their answer is incorrect. It is indeed not always trivial to find a duplicate, nobody can be faulted for that. For all you know, that person spent 10 minutes trying to dig something up, before giving up and writing an answer from scratch. That commitment would warrant an *extra commendation*; you simply can't prove it one way or the other.

Comment: Thank you for responding and you are right. But answering a duplicate is not advised but if answered, there is no penalty. I understand there is a lot of grey area, but what if a user chooses to answer instead of even trying to search a duplicate. This usually happens with people who have newly acquired permission to close but are unaware.

Comment: Yes, so? Is the answer useful and contribute knowledge to the pool? *Great!* Again, you cannot prove **intention** one way or the other. Don't use it as grounds for voting.

Comment: Please accept my apologies but I found a dupe to this discussion. I guess I should have searched more before posting. Not sure what right action is, but would like to request to delete the answer as this post will not add much to portal.

Comment: Oh the irony… :D Let this answer serve as a testbed for itself.

Comment: We're not "punishing that user". We're marking the answer as "not useful", which it indeed is not, because it is redundant, superfluous, and duplicative. Whether the answerer did not bother to find the dup, or made Herculean efforts to do so but failed, does not in the end affect the usefulness of the answer. I don't know where you got the idea that downvotes imply that the answer is "incorrect". They mean exactly one thing, which is that the answer is not useful in the eyes of the downvoter.

Comment: @torazaburo True, *the purpose* of the downvote is not to punish the user, but that is the received net effect. If I was said user who invested that kind of effort, I'd be pretty pissed. And the only reasoning for that downvote would be "somebody else already wrote this elsewhere", which is not a downvote reason under [other circumstances](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291276/476). The "incorrect" was lifted from the OPs question: *"answer can be legit and downvoting can mislead others"*. And I disagree that such an answer is "not useful" at all.

Comment: @deceze Though I agree to *not useful* point, but if you are allowed to answer a duplicate, you will only project 1 or 2 ways and if that solves the problem, OP will not look more. But a duplicate post which is active from long time has more variety of ways to achieve same task and there is lot more info in comments and in answers which OP will miss. In ideal world, we should only have 1 main post, so everyone gets better understanding and knowledge instead of just copy pasting code. I know this is a very controversial statement, but people will only look till their problem is solved.

Comment: @Rajesh Sure, that's why the question is closed as a duplicate and will direct all future visitors to the more canonical version. If OP themselves doesn't bother to investigate more, hardly anything you do will change that. Good engineers follow all the links, bad ones take the first thing that appears to work.

Comment: @deceze I think this question was about **obvious** duplicates. *E-g: "What is a NPE in Java?".* Anyway I approve your thinking.

Comment: My theory is that the people who downvote "duplicate" answers aren't actually downvoting them because they are answering a duplicate. They're actually downvoting them because they're low quality answers, posted in haste, that contribute nothing new and shouldn't have been posted at all. This is a normal, customary, and appropriate reason to downvote, so it's a shame that these downvotes get attributed to the question being a duplicate. I've never seen a high-quality, useful answer to a duplicate question get downvoted, nor have I done so myself.